# Are there any illegal characters when using named parameters in JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm using named parameters in a query to match fields in a map-like data structure. The data structure can have fields, or another map-like data structure. This nested structure is repeatable ad nauseum.

I would like to name the parameters in the query using an XPath like language, that can be parsed to indicate further nested lookups.

So the question is, what characters are legal in a named parameter declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The named parameters should at least be compatible with the restrictions on parameternames in your database.

For Oracle parameter-names consists of a letter optionally followed by more letters, numerals, dollar signs, underscores, and number signs.
Parameternames should not be longer than 30 characters.
So characters such as hyphens, slashes, and spaces are not allowed.

Comment: Do you have a link by chance?

Comment: I guess the answer is just that it's implementation specific. Would've thought there would be a general constraint on this, like in ANSI or something, but I guess not.